# How to resolve await issue in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

Here i am trying to get latest record key p_id value from mongodb collection but i am getting error like :SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function.  So how to resolve this issue?

data.controller.js:

```
module.exports.getData = (req, res, next) => {
 var Product = mongoose.model(req.query.collectionname);
 const getid = await Product.findOne({ p_id: -1 }).limit(1)
 console.log(getid.p_id) 
}
```

Comment: ...make it an async function?

Answer (score 2):

You need to make this function as an `async` function by putting `async` keyword in front of your function like bellow.

```
module.exports.getData = async(req, res, next) => {
 var Product = mongoose.model(req.query.collectionname);
 const getid = await Product.findOne({ p_id: -1 }).limit(1)
 console.log(getid.p_id) 
}
```

Comment: Error: (node:12080) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'p_id' of null

Comment: Could you please check printing `getid` object. is there any value returning from there.

Comment: Do await with in the try... catch...and print thr getId value

Comment: Getting  console.log(getid) is null

Comment: Yeah @RanjithUk it's good practice to follow. it will through any error occurred where the function in runtime.

Comment: null means there is no data found according to your query.

Comment: @Kavitha K do you have product with p_id -1?

Comment: @RanjithUk: I have  p_id in my collection

Comment: Do you have product record with p_id is -1